# Calculate multiplicative inverse of $95$ in group of order $n=101$ which is subgroup of $(\mathbb{F}_{607}^*,\cdot)$

Tags: finite-groups, finite-fields, inverse

In the notes where I'm studying from there is written: "Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ be a subgroup of $(\mathbb{F}_{607}^*,\cdot)$ with $g=64$ and order $n=101$" but that felt strange to me; since I know that every subgroup of another group must have an order which divides the order of the group (Lagrange's theorem), but $607$ is prime. Is there an error in my notes so?

Anyway given $95 \in G$ I've to calculate the inverse: $95^{-1}$

Since the order of $G$ is prime ($101$), I know that every element in $G$ generates $G$, moreover each one of its elements will have an order dividing $|G|$, Consequently:

$$\forall x \in G \ \ \ x^{|G|} = 1 \pmod {|G|}$$

and so:

$$ x^{-1} = x^{|G|-1} \pmod {|G|}$$

so I applied

$$ 95^{-1} = 95^{100} \pmod {101}$$

To handle powers I rewrited it like:

$$95^{100} = (((95)^4)^5)^5 = ((84)^5)^5 = 1^5 = 1$$

But I was expecting to find $95^{-1}$

Could you please tell me where I'm doing wrong and if there are some errors in my notes?

---

I think I need to clarify the whole stuff.

The full description of the exercise is: "Let $G=\langle g\rangle$ be a subgroup of $(\mathbb{F}_{607}^*,\cdot)$ with $g=64$ and order $n=101$.
Consider $h=122 \in G$, find $\log_g h \pmod n$ i.e. $x$ s.t. $h = g^x \Leftarrow\Rightarrow 122 = 64^x \pmod {101}$"

basically is an example on how to apply the "Pollard's $\rho$" algorithm.

at the end of the algorithm I encountered the fraction:

$x = \frac {64}{6} \pmod {101}$ but I think it's a typo and the correct result is:

$$x = \frac {64}{-6} \pmod {101}$$

because num and den are calculated through the differences $64-0$ (num) and $6-12$ (den).

To handle the fraction I thought to multiply the numerator by the inverse of the denominator, so:

$$x = 64 \cdot (-6)^{-1} \pmod {101}$$

But $-6 = 95 \pmod {101}$, hence I thought I needed to find the inverse of $95$ module $101$: $95^{-1} \pmod {101}$

So is $84$ the number I'm searching for?

Comment: The order of the multiplicative group of $\mathbb F_p$ is $p-1$, not $p$ (as $0$ has no inverse).

Comment: You're right, so this answers the first question... But I still don't get what is my mistake in the calculation of the inverse

Comment: The group $G$ is a red herring. The inverse in $G$ is the same as in $\mathbb{F}_{607}$. Apply this with what @lulu is writing.

Comment: Lulu deleted his comment. You have that $a^{p-1}=1$ mod $ p$. Apply this in $\mathbb{F}_{607}$.

Comment: If $95$ is in $G$ then $95^{-1} \equiv 95^{100} \mod 607$...but, I am not so sure that $95$ is in $G.$  I have $95$ as a generator of a group order $202.$

Comment: At the end my mistake was about confusing things. I applied wrongly euler's theorem: $$a^{\varphi(n)} = 1 \pmod n$$ with $a$ and $n$ coprime. So it had to be $$95^{(\varphi(101)-1)} = 95^{100-1} = 95^{99}$$ to get the inverse, I instead computed $$95^{\varphi(101)} = 95^{100}$$ Which is wrong.

Comment: I still think you look at it in the wrong way. In $\mathbb{F}_{607}^*$ the inverse of 95 is 492 and so it is in $G$.

Comment: I don't get it. The inverse of 95 in $|G|$ isn't 84?

Comment: By the way I've another question about the thing: being the group order $101$ and knowing that $n = |\langle 95 \rangle| = |G| = 101$ since $n$ is the order of a generator and so the order of the group, shouldn't be right to calculate $95^{-1}$ with $95^{|G|-1} = 95^{100}$? Why it doesn't work and, instead, Euler's theorem worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So here is my attempt: You are looking at the multiplicative group $G$ generated by $64 \in \mathbb{F}_{607}^*$ i.e. the group of elements

$$ 64,64^2,64^3,\ldots $$

This group is of order $101$ and since $95 \in \mathbb{F}_{607}^*$ has order $202$ the only way of making sense out of $95 \in G$ is to interpret it as $64^{95} \in G$.

But now you are looking for a element $g \in G$ with $g*64^{95}=1 \in G$ i.e. you are looking for a number $m$ with $64^m*64^{95}=1 \in G$ but you already know that $64^{101}=1\in G$ and therefore $64^m*64^{95}=64^{m+95}=64^{101}=1 \in G$ and therefore $m=6$. This means (to follow the notation in your problem) that $6 \in G$ is the inverse of $95$.

Or in other words $64^6$ is the inverse of $64^{95}$ in $G$.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer, take a look if you want =)

Comment: @AlessioMartorana You are killing me. :) That is a completly different question now, First of all you are looking for $122=64^x$  mod $607$ not mod $101$. Then $64/6$ is indeed the right fraction not $64/-6$. No you are looking for the inverse of $6$ mod $101$ which is $6^{99}=17$ mod $101$.

Comment: Mmh that's strange... 
1. The $122=64^x \pmod{101}$ comes directly from the notes, I didn't add nothinng ^^.
2. Why $64/6$ is the right fraction if the difference at den is $6-12 = -6$?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana I don't know about your notes but why would you want to look for $64^x=122$ mod $101$ if $64$ is an element in $\mathbb{F}_{607}^*$ and $122$ is bigger than $101$? This doesn't make sense at all. Secondly I don't know how your algorithm arrives at the conclusion but you have that $64^{17*64}=122$ mod $607$ which gives me confidence that this is indeed the right solution.

Comment: @AlessioMartorana You are looking for $122 \in G$. In $G$ the elements are of the form $64^x$ mod $607$. So you are looking for a number $x$ with $122=64^x$ mod $607$. Looking mod $101$ doesn't make sense.

Comment: $78$ which is also equal to: $17 \cdot 64 \pmod {101}$ is the correct answer as it is reported in the notes. I see your point, actually $122$ is bigger than $101$ so it's not even in $G$ I think... And, instead, the DLP is defined for an $h \in G$...
... I think I will ask to the teacher.
Anyway, could you please explain me why I wasn't finding the inverse of $95$ mod $101$ computing $95^{|G|-1} = 95^{100}$? Shouldn't it be true that $95^{101} = 1 \pmod {101}$ knowing that $101$ is the order of the group and $95$ is a generator?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana You got it slightly wrong. Fermat's little theorem says that $a^{p-1}=1$ mod $p$. So you should calculate $95^{100}=1$ mod $101$ i.e. $95^{99}=95^{-1}$ mod $101$.

Comment: Yeah, in fact Fermat little and Euler's theorem held. But shouldn't be also valid that every generator at the power of the order of the group must be equal to one? That is: $$95^{|G|} = 95^{101} = 1$$ from which: $$95^{101-1} = 95^{100} = 95^{-1}$$

Comment: @AlessioMartorana You are confusing multiplication and addition. $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ is a additive group of order $101$. The neutral element is $0$ and indeed if you take any element and add it $101$ times you get $101*a =0$ mod $101$.

Comment: So you're telling me that my $|G|$ is the group $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ ? But how can you say that? Where do we get information about the internal composition law of the group ($+$ in this case)?

Comment: I mean, couldn't it be a multiplicative group of order $101$?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana Your group is not $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ but it is isomorphic to it by $$ 64^x \mapsto x $$. $G$ is a multiplicative group and $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$ is a additive group. The whole point of taking the logarithm is changing your multiplicative problem into a additive one. That's why you use these  isomorphism. Think about it: in $G$ your not calculating mod $101$ but mod $607$. And of course for every element in $g\in G$  you have $g^{101}=1$ mod $607$.

Comment: I can see the isomorfism by that $f$ (e.g. $f(64^x \cdot 64^x) = f(64^x) + f(64^x) = x+x$ and the equivalence of the operations is mantained in the two groups), but still I didn't get why the statements for multiplicative groups which I wrote before (for example  $95^{|G|} = 95^{101} = 1$) don't hold. I mean, is a multiplicative cyclic group right? So that equation must hold, what's wrong in this?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana Please try to read my comment again. I said that of course it holds that $g^{101}=1$ mod $607$ which is the multiplication in $G$. What doesn't hold is that $g^{101}=1$ mod $101$. You are confusing the operations here. If you calculate mod $101$ you are in $\mathbb{Z}/101\mathbb{Z}$. This means you apllied the isomorphism already. This isomorphism IS the logarithm. Thats all I'm trying to say.

Comment: ... I think I forgot (again) that a subgroup $|G|$ is a set which is a group w.r.t. the operation of the "mother"group... So $|G|$ is a group with the multiplication $\pmod {607}$, That's the point, right?

Comment: @AlessioMartorana Precisely!

Comment: Ok, I'm an idiot and you're a very kind man. Thank you very much =)

Comment: @AlessioMartorana you're very welcome. :) Have a great day!

Answer (score 1):

Since $64^{101}\equiv 1\mod 607$, the inverse of $64^{95}$ is $$64^6=2^{36}=512^4\equiv(-95)^4\equiv(527)^2\equiv(-80)^2\equiv 6400\equiv 330\mod 607.$$

Comment: That's much better. :) I delete my earlier comments to keep it clean.

Comment: Once  the problem phrasing has been cleared :o)

Answer (score 0):

First, write $\;95=5\cdot19\;$ , and now

$$607\cdot2=1214\implies 1215\div5=243\implies 5^{-1}=243\pmod{607}$$